# collection COUNT, FIRST and LAST in UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a table of a `%ROWTYPE`:

```
TYPE t_my_tab IS TABLE OF my_config%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
my_tab t_my_tab;
```

I load it using some dynamic SQL:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql BULK COLLECT INTO my_tab;
```

I'm getting an error on:

```
UPDATE ... SET x = mytab.count ...;

PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "MY_TAB"."COUNT": invalid identifier
```

But when I assign the value to another variable, it works fine:

```
v_count NUMBER;
v_count := mytab_tab.count;
UPDATE ... SET x = v_count ...;
```

Is there a way to avoid this reassignment?  I have the same problem when I use `my_tab.first` and `my_tab.last` in a `FOR` loop.

Comment: ah, good point. added it to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silly me... [collection methods cannot be called from SQL statements.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/collections.htm#i27396)